# sometimes my database does not update with the same code

Tags: database, sql-update, android-room

my code in android studio and JAVA language has a problem with its database. I have a edittext in a fragment and I use it for update database. the database is initialized using Room library in activity and the DAO file is defined public and static in mainActivity, and use method DAO.update(photo) in a fragment, but sometimes when type in edittext it updates the field in database but sometimes not, I do not know why? can you please help me on it and do you have same experience?

related code in activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public AppDB appDB;
    public static AlbumDAO albumDAO;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        
        
        appDB= Room.databaseBuilder(this, AppDB.class, "db_App")
                .allowMainThreadQueries()
                .build();
        albumDAO= appDB.getAlbumDAO();
```

and then I used the database initialized in main activity in this fragment:

```
public class PhotoFragment extends Fragment {


private Album album;
EditText title;
String inputTitle;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.album=getArguments().getParcelable("key");

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.fragment_photo,container,false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

 
        title=view.findViewById(R.id.txt_postTitle);
        title.setText(album.getTitle());
        title.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            inputTitle=charSequence.toString();
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                album.setTitle(inputTitle);
                albumDAO.updateAlbum(album);

            }
        });
}
```

and the albumDAO is:

```
@Dao
public interface AlbumDAO {

    @Insert
    long addAlbum(Album album);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM tbl_album")
    List<Album> getAllAlbums();

    @Update
    void updateAlbum(Album album);

    @Delete
    void deleteAlbum(Album album);

    @Query("DELETE FROM tbl_album")
    void deleteAllAlbum();
}
```

and the Album class is:

```
@Entity(tableName = "tbl_album")
public class Album implements Parcelable {

    @PrimaryKey (autoGenerate = true)
    private  int id;

    private  String title;

    public Album() {
    }

    protected Album(Parcel in) {
        title = in.readString();
    }

    public static final Creator<Album> CREATOR = new Creator<Album>() {
        @Override
        public Album createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Album(in);
        }

        @Override
        public Album[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Album[size];
        }
    };

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {
        parcel.writeString(title);
    }


    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the overidden `afterTextChanged` method. You are updating the database and then changing the title in the album, so the database will not reflect the changed title.

Try using :-

```
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            album.setTitle(inputTitle); //<<<<< MOVED UP
            albumDAO.updateAlbum(album);
        }
```

You can also utilise the value (int) returned by the @Update annotated function, to see if anything has been updated by changing it to:-

```
@Update
int updateAlbum(Album album)
```

Then you could use something along the lines of:-

```
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            album.setTitle(inputTitle);
            if (album.setTitle(inputTitle)> 0) {
                .... do whatever here to indicate update was OK
            } else {
                .... do whatever here to indicate not updated
            }
        }
```

Comment: yes you are right, before it was like your suggestion and now also I edited and changed the order of lines under afterTextChanged, but still it has problem and sometimes works and sometimes not. I think it is related the way I initialized albumDAO in main activity as a public static value and use it in other fragments, in this way I did not use singletone and the instance in the fragments.